# Android device is stopped getting detected in linux

Tags: linux-mint, usb, usb-drive, usb-device, adb

My motorola android mobile was getting detected initially in linux mint 17.3 . Then I was using it for android studio where mobile is getting detected and could do testing android app via my mobile.

Now issue is, in android studio adb could detect my mobile but in linux file explorer it is not detected. And my issue is as same as [this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/127950/recognition-of-usb-drive)

Android studio (here it is getting detected)

[image: android studio]

lsusb

[image: lsusb]

lsusb -v

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 22b8:2e82 Motorola PCS 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x22b8 Motorola PCS
  idProduct          0x2e82 
  bcdDevice            2.28
  iManufacturer           1 motorola
  iProduct                2 XT1022
  iSerial                 3 ZX1B343RHV
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 MTP
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
        bInterval               6
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: obvious question, but have you enabled the connection on the android device? i.e. gone into settings and enabled "developer mode" debugging via USB and kept the android device in an unlocked state?

Comment: ya I did that too. Initially I used to connect it and it will be mounted without issue. But suddenly it doesn't get mounted

Comment: When I find the usb bus doesn't detect USB devices, I usually just reboot

Comment: should reboot mobile or system?

Comment: I meant reboot the desktop - do you have chrome browser? what is the result of typing `chrome://inspect/#devices` inthe address bar when your device is connected?

Comment: ya it is listing mobile device

Comment: And also, initially when i used to connect it, lsusb output will not show as "motorola pcs". Now only it shows such

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem over and over until i noticed that if `chrome://inspect/#devices` adb devices list comes up empty.

Close the tab (or Chrome), plug your device back, and it should work.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. It's so frustrating ... you have the phone, cable, and linux all potentially going wonky.

Answer (score 1):

If Chrome is opened with `chrome://inspect/#devices` then adb devices stop showing the devices.

Fix would be close and open chrome.